# Gps get location without internet

Tags: android, gps, google-maps-android-api-2

i have next situation. I have GPSTracker in my app. And i need to get my location without internet, on my nexus 4 it works great, but on Lg gt 540 (android 2.1 for default, but i install 2.3.3) it does not works. How to solve this problem?

Comment: If really, that is the problem, because Internet access is not required to get location.

Comment: Maybe in android 2.1 it needed? But i reboot it on 2.3

Comment: you are getting locations for maps v2 api then internet is definately required.

Comment: Does software of lg gt 540 support maps v2, maybe gps modul is old?

Comment: maps api v2 is supported for android api 8 and above.

Comment: 2.1 is api 7. But i reboot it to 2.3. I think i must to try this app in device where 2.3. is default android version

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use phone GPS without internet. But only when you previously downloaded the map. For example, Google Maps, allows you to pre-download a 50 sq km map for temporary offline use, which will help in some situations.

But the problem is that it never update your current position, it happens with me when go somewhere there is no internet connection so I pre-download the map. It show me the offline saved map but it can’t update my current position.